# I've been tasked with migrating a 2003 AD domain to 2008 native mode - what should I look out for?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Apart from running adprep etc has anyone done this & had issues. I don't have the luxury of having a test environment....

Comment: I hope you mean 2008 R2 and not 2008. 2008 is three versions old now.

Answer (score 2):

> Apart from running adprep etc has anyone done this & had issues

I've done dozens. There are never issues with directory services, only with other things in the environment like network appliances that use DES, or Windows NT4 trusts that are no longer supported with 2008 R2 domain controllers.

[Read the documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6170), understand the documentation, plan accordingly.

Comment: apologies, yes I do mean R2. As far as i can ascertain all domain controllers are running R2 but the domain is running at 2003 following the decommission of a 2003 server last month. Your pointer to the MS documentation is a great help - many thanks